# python3-yaml needs dependency python3-yaml

Tags: linux, python-3.x, debian, yaml

I am trying to install lutris on SteamOS using Debian, to do so I require python3-yaml; which is becoming a nightmare to install. I found the debian file for python3-yaml online and have checked that I have installed all the dependencies required however I always end up with a strange error stating that the dependency "python3-yaml" is not satisfiable and I am unsure if this is a glitch in the software I am using or if python3-yaml actually needs python3-yaml to be installed.

[image]

I have attempted using normal yaml however that has not contributed anything towards my situation.

Could someone suggest a method for me to use to install python3-yaml and give me a few steps for doing it, thank you kindly.

Comment: What happens when you `dpkg -i <the package file>`?

Comment: Suggestions : `# apt install --reinstall python3-yaml` ..... And : `# pip3 install yaml-[version]` ... Latest is `# pip3 install yaml-1.3` https://pypi.org/project/yaml-1.3/

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this

```
dpkg -i python3-yaml.deb

apt-get install -f
```

Comment: »» `dpkg -i package.deb` «« → The right command is `# gdebi package.deb` .... which will also install the dependencies.

Comment: I tried this however I still get the same error
"Errors were encountered while processing:
python3-yaml"